# Rails 4: With devise, how can I authenticate a user just based on user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cookies, devise

I have two classes of users, those who provide an email address and optional password and (even more) lightweight users who provide only their name.  When lightweight users return to my site --even after closing their browser-- their name should be automatically remembered and they should be automatically signed in with their lightweight permissions.  Given that name may not be unique, I want to sign the lightweight users in based on their user ID.

(Lightweight users can become full users by adding their email address later.)

I am using Devise, and my user.rb file includes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def password_required?
    false
  end

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  def remember_me
    true
  end
```

In the devise.rb initializer, I have tried setting

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :user_id ]
```

but it didn't have an effect other than breaking authentication for those users who have an email address.

With config.authentication_keys = [:email], returning users who have provided an email address are successfully logged into the site when they return even if the browser is restarted/session cookie is destroyed.  However, returning users with just a name are forgotten when the browser is restarted.  In both cases a remember_user_token cookie is present.

Looking at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address, I may need to overwrite Devise's find_for_database_authentication method, but I'm not sure what to put in that or if that will be enough; I've tried some variations of that without success.

Comment: So if you don't want email authentication, that should be fine, but with a slightly change, instead of using `user_id`, user `id`, take a look at the article in the wiki it is really helpful https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Comment: Thanks Kurenn.  Not sure exactly what you mean about user [space] id?  I took a look at the attached, that was what I was referring to about the other research, and it is helpful but it didn't get me all the way there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out; here is the answer in case others have the same issue.

The relevant sign-in process happens in the Rememberable module of Devise.

Devise stores the saved user information between sessions in the remember_user_token cookie.  The cookie contains both the user ID and a remember token.

If the email and password are both blank, the remember token will also be blank, causing an internal Devise comparison (secure_compare) to fail.  This will result in the session being lost and the remember_user_token cookie to be destroyed.

To fix this, you can set a temporary password for users that don't have one.  One approach is the following.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def sign_up_params
    new_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_up)

    # If no password is supplied for new user, create one
    # This is needed because Devise requires a password for Rememberable to work,
    # even if password_required? is set to false in the User model.
    if (new_params[:password] == nil)
      new_params[:password] = Devise.friendly_token
    end

    # return the modified (and further sanitized) params list
    new_params
  end
end
```

It's up to you, depending on what you're trying to do, whether you want to let the user know about the temporary password they have. Or you could have them reset it if they later add an email address which will also result in them confirming their email address.